# Flutter google maps , how to make a gradient in polylines?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, linear-gradients

Is there any way to make the polylines a gradient, and not just the same color?

That code is working well = polylines created but i can't add gradient
 //Create polylines

```
  void _setPolylLines() {
    _polylines.add(
      Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId("polylineHistoryRoute"),
        points: polyLinesLatLongs,
        width: 4,
        patterns: <PatternItem>[PatternItem.dash(25), PatternItem.gap(15)],
        color: Color.fromRGBO(86, 168, 235, 1),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package, it seems that the feature to add a gradient polyline is not yet available for this package as there's an existing [feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47232) to support gradient colors to polyline/plolygons.

However, if you are using [flutter_map](https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map) package, perhaps you can try [this](https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map/pull/452#issuecomment-647113700).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already found out that so far the gradient in the package google_maps_flutter is not supported